# Sum in Spark for a Column Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

So I have a dataset and what I am doing is taking a column out of the dataset, than mapping it to a key value pair. The problem is I can't sum my value:

```
position = 1
myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[position]))
print myData.take(10)
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: (“Column", fields[0])).groupByKey().map(lambda (Column, values): (Column, sum(float(values))))
print myData2.take(10)
```

This prints out the following:

```
[u'18964', u'18951', u'18950', u'18949', u'18960', u'18958', u'18956', u'19056', u'18948', u'18969’]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

So When I changed it to:

```
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: (“Column", fields[0])).groupByKey().map(lambda (Column, values): (values))
```

I see the following:

```
[<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fab6c43f1d0>]
```

If I do just:

```
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: (“Column", fields[0]))
```

I get this:

```
[('Column', u'18964'), ('Column', u'18951'), ('Column', u'18950'), ('Column', u'18949'), ('Column', u'18960'), ('Column', u'18958'), ('Column', u'18956'), ('Column', u'19056'), ('Column', u'18948'), ('Column', u'18969’)]
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).groupByKey().map(lambda (Column, values): (Column, sum(values)))
```